# Cache relation laravel with orderby

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to know how can I cache laravel relation with orderby in controller ?

Currently I have this in my controller :

> MyController.php

```
$replies = $message->replies()->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
```

> MessageEntity.php

```
/* Message has many Replies */
public function replies() {
    return \Cache::remember('messages_' . $this->id . '_replies', $this->expiration, function () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Entities\ReplyEntity', 'fk_message_id', 'id')->get();
    });
}
```

But I have this error :

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using get() in your relation method, the method wont return the relation but will return the list from db, and that would make sense, because you don not want to cache the relation, but you want to cache the data:

you may add orderBy clause to your query Builder in the function before using 'get()'

```
public function replies() {
    return \Cache::remember('messages_' . $this->id . '_replies', $this->expiration, function () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Entities\ReplyEntity', 'fk_message_id', 'id')->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
    });
}
```

please not if your order by columns or direction are not always the same, you should include the order direction and columns in the key of you cache

as a personal opinion, the relation method should represent the relation only, without get and cache, so you can use it somewhere else.
the cache should be in the repository of the model ('MessagesRepository')

Answer (score 0):

It is because of you are retrieving a collection and the orderBy() is a query method.

You will need to change your entity method to

```
    /* Message has many Replies */
public function replies() {
    return \Cache::remember('messages_' . $this->id . '_replies', $this->expiration, function () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Entities\ReplyEntity', 'fk_message_id', 'id')->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
    });
}
```

and in the controller just get it with

```
$replies = $message->replies();
```

Or use an alternative method for collection sortBy( https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby )